# Uploading a file with Amazon S3 with a specific folder structure

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I'm using **Amazon's cloud thingee with S3 to upload files.**

I would need it to store and distinguish different user's different logs. So far I can only upload a file to the root, so I cannot really make folders on the fly, which I would require.

I use this code to upload such file, without directory structure:

```
   AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY));

   File file = FileUtil.writeTextFile(fileName, "test content");

   PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_ID, fileName, file);
   s3Client.putObject(por);


   ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
   override.setContentType("text");
```

**But I would need dynamic file structure for different users and such, so how could I include a file structure for example like [user_id]/[timestamp]/actual_file.ext ?**

I've tried with simply adding the path to the BUCKET_ID of course that's not working.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **mimic** folder by adding prefix to your **S3 object key**.

Your bucket name does not vary but you can filter bucket's objects by prefix (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#API_ListObjectsV2_RequestSyntax).

So you can have in your bucket MyBucket, different objects:

- user1/ts1/firstobject
- user1/ts2/secondobject
- userN/tsN/object

You can find an AWS doc here on S3 prefix management: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html

**Updated**

In your case, the fileName should not be actual_file.ext but  [user_id]/[timestamp]/actual_file.ext as it is the S3 Object key.

`PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_ID, [user_id]/[timestamp]/[fileName], file);`

Comment: Errr... Don't get it, I would need the solution for Amazon's Android version of S3 SDK, not with URLs.